# href com Submit no Asp.net core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tenho uma view _LoginPartial no qual possui um link para SAIR (Fazer Logout do sistema).

```
<li role="presentation">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem">
         <i class="icon wb-power" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sair
      </a>                       
</li>
```

Como faço para que ele seja `type="submit"` e dispare para minha action `asp-action="Logout"`?

```
<form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Olá @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
            </li>

            <li class="dropdown">
                <a class="navbar-avatar dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" aria-expanded="false"
                   data-animation="scale-up" role="button">
                    <span class="avatar avatar-online">
                        <img src="../../assets/portraits/5.jpg" alt="...">
                        <i></i>
                    </span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Perfil</a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-settings" aria-hidden="true"></i> Configurações</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-power" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sair</a>                       
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como você quer apenas sair do sistema, não há necessidade de um submit, basta colocar o href apontando para o seu método, exemplo:

**View**

```
 <a href="~/Login/Logout" role="menuitem">
     <i class="icon wb-power" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sair
 </a>
```

**Controller**

```
public class LoginController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Logout()
    {      
        //retorna para a pagina inicial
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá Cassio!! Ele dá exibe uma msg informando que não foi possível encontrar a página... Eu chequei a rota certinho, mas não vai.

Comment: Olá Jalber, então, eu te dei um exemplo, se você copiar meu código, você deve criar a função Logout também, se não, não ira encontrar mesmo.

Comment: Ela já existe! Está no controller Account:      [HttpPost]
        [Route("account/logout")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
        }

Comment: e como ta seu href?

Comment: <a href="~/account/logout" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-power" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sair</a>

Comment: Cara tem algum erro na rota, quando você clica ele vai para onde? qual link aparece na barra de endereço?

Comment: https://localhost:44355/home/account/logout

Comment: Então aí que tá o erro, coloque assim no seu href: //account/logout/

Comment: Estranho. Não funciona....

Comment: Está indo para a mesma rota?

Comment: https://account/logout/

Comment: Troque o href por: Url.Action("logout", "account")

Comment: Ainda não funciona..... Se eu fizer assim, funciona:  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log out</button>

Comment: @JalberRomano A sua action atende o método POST e você está usando um link (que envia GET)

Comment: @LINQ e como eu faço um post usando o javascript mesmo? <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="menuitem"><i class="icon wb-power" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sair</a>

Comment: @JalberRomano por que você precisa de um post?

Comment: É que no meu modelo Identity, criado pelo asp.net core, é criado com esse padrão Automaticamente. Como eu estou usando uma tema da web, preciso adaptá-lo.